# is there any regular expression for "year-year"?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to have a regular expression for year in JavaScript. for example I want to check the textbox input is **2008-2015**. I mean have a "dash" between two years. what is it's regular expression?

no one of the following expressions working!

```
/^\d{4}-\d{4}$/; 

/^(\d{4})-(\d{4})$/;

/^\d{4}\-\d{4}$/;

/^\d{4}\\-\d{4}$/;
```

and I want to have OR in that expression. I mean it supports **2008-2015 or 2012** (`^\d{4}$`) .

edit:
my js code is:

```
function validateYear() {
        var dob_courseYear = document.getElementById(<%=txt_courseYear.ClientID%>").value;

        //pattern = /^\d{4}-\d{4}$/; //^\d{4}$
        //pattern = /^(\d{4})-(\d{4})$/;
        //pattern = /^\d{4}\\-\d{4}$/;
        //pattern = /^\d{4}(-\d{4})?$/;
        pattern = /^\d{4}(?:-\d{4})?$/m;
        if (dob_courseYear == null || dob_courseYear == "" || !pattern.test(dob_courseYear)) {
            errMessage += "Year is incorrect...\n";
        }
    }
```

I tried all your suggestion. but not working and alerts me the error message!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @GordonLinoff why? js would support `\d`

Comment: @s.m What do you mean by not-working? If you want to deal with two or more lines, you must need to add multiline modifier.

Comment: @epascarello no. there is no space there.

Comment: @AvinashRaj when I want ti js check the textbox input, & alert the rong input. (for example 2002+2005 is rong)

Comment: Man, your edit really changed the question....

Comment: The first two are fine. What do you want to happen?

Comment: @JustinMorgan please take a look at the edited post

Comment: @GordonLinoff - In JS, `\d` == `[0-9]`. But there's no reason to think he has a problem with unicode numbers anyway.

Comment: Once again, your pattern is fine. What do you expect to happen? Also, your code has a stray `"`.

Comment: @JustinMorgan the problem is when i entered the correct year even, it alerts me!!

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Your pattern is fine based on the description you've given us. Reexamine your assumptions, along with the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
/^\d{4}(-\d{4})?$/
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/22)

Answer (score 1):

> and I want to have OR in that expression. I mean it supports 2008-2015 or 2012 (^\d{4}$) .

Just make the second part as optional.

```
/^\d{4}(?:-\d{4})?$/m;
```